# Spring PageableArgumentResolver deprecated, how to use PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

This is my current PageableResolver:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(1, 5));
    argumentResolvers.add(new ServletWebArgumentResolverAdapter(resolver));
}
```

But the PageableArgumentResolver is deprecated, and linked to the PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver, which i suppose we can register without an Adapter, like this:

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setFallbackPageable(new PageRequest(0, 5));
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
}
```

First of all the implementation of new class PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver is a little different, since `new PageRequest(1, 5)` refers to the 2. page so i had to use `new PageRequest(0, 5)` in order it displays the first page.

But i still have problems with this new object. First load of the pagination bar is perfect when I call the URL without parameters (neither page.page nor page.size). Then when i want to move on the pagination bar, we are calling the same url with 2 parameters (eg. page.page=3&page.size=5), there is still displayed the first page. I think this new Resolver needs more than just these 2 parameters, so that it doesn't activate the fallback condition. Do you have any idea how to work with this PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just found the answer in the Implementation of this class. We now need 2 changes for this new class:

1. The parameters do not have the prefix "page" anymore. "`..?page=2&size=5`" works.
2. Since the page 1 refers to the 2. page now, we have to redefine our parameters in the pagination.jsp: `..?page=${item.number-1}` instead of `..?page=${item.number}`

Answer (score 5):

You can change the parameter names, using this methods: setPageParameterName,  setSizeParameterName.

Set this setOneIndexedParameters to true if your initial page is 1.

```
@Override
public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
    PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
    resolver.setPageParameterName("page.page");
    resolver.setSizeParameterName("page.size");
    resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
    super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
}
```

Comment: Like this, you not affect your front-end.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the parameter names in you bean definition:

```
    <annotation-driven>
    <argument-resolvers>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
            <beans:property name="maxPageSize" value="7"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="oneIndexedParameters" value="true"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="pageParameterName" value="page.page"></beans:property>
            <beans:property name="sizeParameterName" value="page.size"></beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
    </argument-resolvers>
</annotation-driven>
```

This will override the default parameter names.

Comment: This does not seem to work. Looking at the documentation for argument-resolvers, it says: "Using this option does not override the built-in support for resolving handler method arguments. To customize the built-in support for argument resolution configure RequestMappingHandlerAdapter directly."

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521280/spring-data-rest-configure-pagination