# Spring Data Rest - Configure pagination

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

Using Spring Data REST with JPA in version 2.1.0.

How can I configure the pagination in order to have the page argument starting at index 1 instead of 0 ?

I have tried setting a  custom `HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` with an `mvc:argument-resolvers`, but that doesn't work:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
      <bean class="org.springframework.data.web.HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver">
          <property name="oneIndexedParameters" value="true"/>
      </bean>
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Note that this behaviour is perfectly coherent with the documentation for `mvc:argument-resolver` that says:

> Using this option **does not override the built-in support** for
>   resolving handler method arguments. To customize the built-in support
>   for argument resolution configure RequestMappingHandlerAdapter
>   directly.

But how can I achieve this ? If possible, in a clean and elegant way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use to do it using a customizer, which is something that they keep adding for more and more components with every new version:

```
@Bean
public PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer pageableResolverCustomizer() {
    return resolver -> resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
}
```

You can put this in any @Configuration class, but ideally you should put it (with any other customization) in one that implements RepositoryRestConfigurer.

Comment: This didn't exist at that time, but it looks the best solution to do it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to do so is to subclass `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` and include your class into your configuration:

```
class CustomRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

  @Override
  @Bean
  public HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {

    HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = super.pageableResolver();
    resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
    return resolver;
  }
}
```

In your XML configuration, replace:

```
<bean class="….RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration" />
```

with

```
<bean class="….CustomRestMvcConfiguration" />
```

or import the custom class instead of the standard one in your JavaConfig file.

Comment: This works like a charm. And it's less cumbersome than using a BeanPostProcessor. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone know if this is an easily configurable property now? Seems like a thing that should just be a flag, especially in something like Spring Boot

Answer (score 2):

I have configured the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` using a `BeanPostProcessor`, however I believe that's neither clean, nor elegant. That looks more like a hack. There must be a better way ! I'm giving the code below just for reference.

```
public class RequestMappingHandlerAdapterCustomizer implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof RequestMappingHandlerAdapter) {
              RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = (RequestMappingHandlerAdapter)bean;
              List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> customArgumentResolvers = adapter.getCustomArgumentResolvers();
              if(customArgumentResolvers != null) {
                  for(HandlerMethodArgumentResolver customArgumentResolver : customArgumentResolvers) {
                      if(customArgumentResolver instanceof HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver) {
                          HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver hateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver = (HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver)customArgumentResolver;
                          hateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
                      }
                  }
              }
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName)
            throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }   

}

<beans ...>
  <bean class="util.spring.beanpostprocessors.RequestMappingHandlerAdapterCustomizer" />
</beans>
```