# Reconfigure Spring Data Rest to Index at Page 1

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I thought I had this figured out but the setting does not seem to change the index.  `setOneIndexedParameters(true)`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = new PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver();
        resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
        argumentResolvers.add(resolver);
        super.addArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
    }

.... other config stuff
```

Expected result is that instead of the base URL for spring data rest being `http://localhost:8080/api/text?page=0&size=20` it would change to `http://localhost:8080/api/text?page=1&size=20` as the initial page.

Did I do this correctly or is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was here [Spring Data Rest - Configure pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23521280/spring-data-rest-configure-pagination)

I moved the configuration to extending `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`

```
@Configuration
class CustomRestMvcConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver pageableResolver() {

        HateoasPageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver resolver = super.pageableResolver();
resolver.setOneIndexedParameters(true);
return resolver;
    }
}
```