# Spring Data - PageRequest one-based page index

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-commons

I am trying to configure Pageable and PageRequest for page number starting from 1 instead of 0. Using below code Pageable is configured successfully:

```
@Configuration 
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport 
public class JPAConfiguration { 

    @Bean 
    Pageable HandlerMethodArgumentResolverCustomizer pageCustomizer(){ 
        returns -> p.setOneIndexedParameters(true); 
    } 

}
```

And now if I call endpoint using:

> /myEndpoint?page=1&size=2

I get the records of first page which means 1-based page size is working. However the response has below information related to pagination:

```
"totalElements": 9, 
"last": false, 
"totalPages": 5, 
"size": 2, 
"number": 0, 
"numberOfElements": 2, 
"first": true, 
"sort": { 
    "sorted": true, 
    "unsorted": false 
}
```

If you notice the 'number' is 0 which means it is still 0-based. How can I configure it to be 1-based?

Thanks in advance.

I am using: **SpringBoot:2.0.0, spring-data-commons: 2.0.5**

Comment: you see [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134451/reconfigure-spring-data-rest-to-index-at-page-1)?

Comment: As I am not using Repository Rest, so I am not sure if it works for me or not.